# Javafx bar chart X axis does not scale properly when updating data

Tags: java, javafx, bar-chart

I am trying to implement a bar chart using Javafx. The chart works fine if I plot the data only once. But when I update the data and re-plot the chart, the X axis scale remains the same, while all data is updated correctly. Please check the following images.

This is the correct chart which plots data by weeks

[data by week](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7WxN.png)

When I update the data, the chart turns into

[data by month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3t8F.png)

You can see the data has been updated, but the X axis does not scale correctly. Interesting thing is, when I plot the chart again without changing the data, the X axis becomes normal like this.

[data by month2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBVeV.png)

The codes are as follows:

```
private static void drawChart(int timeMode)
{
    stayAvg = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();
    stayAvg.setName("Avg.Stay (mins)");

    // add data to the dataset
    if (timeMode == 1)
    {
        for (int i = firstWeek; i <= lastWeek; i++)
        {
            stayAvg.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(weeks[i], weeksTotalCount[i]));
        }
    }
    else if (timeMode == 2)
    {
        for (int i = firstMonth; i <= lastMonth; i++)
        {
            stayAvg.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(months[i], monthsTotalCount[i]));
        }
    }

    // display chart
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // plot data sets to the chart
            // Update UI here.
            // set up tooltips when cursor hovers on bars
            sbc.setData(FXCollections.observableArrayList(stayAvg));
            stayAvg.getData().forEach(d -> {
                    Tooltip tip = new Tooltip();
                    tip.setText(d.getYValue() + "\n" + d.getXValue());
                    Tooltip.install(d.getNode(), tip);
            });
            // sbc is a StackedBarChart
            sbc.setTitle("Average Stay");
            chart.setScene(scene);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: 1) What's this got to do with Swing? 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I did not pay attention to Java nomenclature previously. I will edit the codes.

Answer (score 1):

You could try disabling the bar-chart's animation:

```java
chart.setAnimated(false);
```

This will prevent the seemingly "smooth" transition between bar-chart updates, and thus preventing those unexpected visual bugs like overcrowded bar labels.

This is inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129970/how-can-i-update-javafx-barchart-in-swing-application) question and works in my case.

Answer (score 1):

At first, enable chart animation.At the end disable chat animation.

```
    lineChart.getData().clear();
    lineChart.setAnimated(true);// enable animation
    XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();

    String query = "SELECT time, total_purchase FROM sales WHERE date = '"+ 
    text.getText() +"'";

    con = new Connector().connector();
    pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    rs.beforeFirst();

    while(rs.next()){

        String time = rs.getString(rs.findColumn("time"));
        float purchase = rs.getFloat(rs.findColumn("total_purchase"));

        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(time, purchase));
    }
    lineChart.getData().addAll(series);
    lineChart.setAnimated(false);// disable animation
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not to setData each time you draw:

```
 sbc.setData(FXCollections.observableArrayList(stayAvg));
```

And instead doing:

```
private static void drawChart(int timeMode)
{
 sbc.getData().clear();

// add data to the dataset
if (timeMode == 1)
{
    for (int i = firstWeek; i <= lastWeek; i++)
    {
        stayAvg.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(weeks[i], weeksTotalCount[i]));
    }
}
else if (timeMode == 2)
{
    for (int i = firstMonth; i <= lastMonth; i++)
    {
        stayAvg.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(months[i], monthsTotalCount[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it does not work. If setData is not called, there would be nothing in the chart.